# UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning UINavigationController push and pop

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, uiviewanimationtransition

I've successfully implemented `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` on a `navigationController` and have a nice custom transition on `iOS 7`.

The problem is now the navigation bar doesn't do the normal push animation for the navigation items anymore. Instead now, the navigation items just fade in and fade out. I'd the navigation items to slide in & out and fade like a normal push and pop would do.

*Does anyone know how to hook up the navigation bar push and pop animation with the custom transition?*

Comment: are you using storyboard or...?

Comment: did you use CATransaction Animation between push and pop

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing anything wrong. That's how it's supposed to work for custom animated navigation bar transitions in iOS 7. You get a cross-dissolve animation instead of the normal push animation.

If you listen to WWDC session 218 you will hear this mentioned and see it in the first demo.